# Got Error : While installing TeX Live 2020 on Windows 10, it shows installation failed at last

Tags: texlive-2020

I have tried Installing TeX Live 2020 on my Windows 10 operating system, all the packages (4032) have been installed, but at the end of the installation I got "Installation has failed":

[image: Screen Shot of Error Message]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Did you disable your antivirus during installation?

Comment: Hello AndreC ,
Actually not, i have not disabled my antivirus during installation.

what i should do next for TeX Live Installation, i have ran this exe file " install-tl-windows.exe" downloaded from www.tug.org/texlive

Your help will be gratefull dear.

Comment: Yes, during installation disabling the antivirus fixes most of the problems.

Comment: Ohkk, AndreC

so now i have to disable antivirus...... and i should have to delete all file that installed and remove temp file right ?

or anything else i have to do before installing 2nd time  ??

Comment: Please suggest me few more things so that i can install Tex Live successfully in 2nd times.

Comment: Usually, it is sufficient to delete the files and folders that have been installed.

Comment: Okay AndreC, Thank you for you information.....

i will try again installing, if i will get problem i will update.....

Comment: Actually AndreC, My friend does not have any antivirus in his system...... but still get this same error on Windows 10 ...... 2 days back......

Comment: can you tell what to do next ?

Comment: Are you the administrator of your windows 10?

Comment: yes, i was running Tex Live exe file as administrator.

Comment: My friend as did the same way as admininstrator

Comment: Did you disable the firewall?

Comment: I have to disable Windows Defender and externally installed antivirus right ??.......... or i have to disable Windows firewall ??

Comment: No, the Windows Defender antivirus is generally not a problem. Just do what it says here [installing latex on windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1530895)

Comment: Okay i will follow those instructions and let you know, thank you for you time brother.